# How to Open Raw HTML (.html) in React 'Public' Folder?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I'm creating static `.html` files from my React Apps with https://github.com/gajus/usus (background job)

and put it in the `/public` and make new folder ie. `/article/`

**Issue :** whenever I open that `html` file ie. `aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd.html` it is rendered firstly and then the `index.html` show up at last.

> How to properly open `.html` file in the React Js app?

**NB :** I'm using `create-react-app`

Answer (score 2):

say, you have `test.html` in `public/article/`, then in the `src/example.js` you can use `<a href='/article/test.html' target='_blank'>link to test.html</a>` to open `test.html` in a new window.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider editing your answer to describe the solution instead of referring to an attached image only. It will be more useful that way, as the content can be indexed and found later

Comment: yes, your answer is useful, but the format is a mess.